# Sum involving the number of zeros of $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, decimal-expansion, conjectures

I'm currently interested in sums involving digit-functions. Especially, I'd like to calculate the following sum:
$$
s=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_0(k)}{k\left(k+1\right)}}
$$
Where $a_0(k)$ is the number of zeros in the base $10$ representation of $k$.

Normally, such sums can be tackled by considering products of the form $P(x,q)=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+f_1(x)q^{10^k}+…+f_9(x)q^{9\cdot 10^k}\right)}$, but this approach seems not to work here, because the zero is a bit problematic.

Numerically, it seems that $s=\frac{10+\gamma+\psi{(0.1)}}{9}$ where $\psi$ is the digamma function.

Comment: That's an interesting question, you're right you can not find adequate functions for the number of zeros, you can see my answer and if you need help leave me a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e(n)$ be the number of non-zero digits of $n$ then:
$a_0(k)=\lfloor \log_{10}(k)\rfloor - e(k) $ so the idea is to compute:
$$s_1=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\lfloor \log_{10}(k)\rfloor}{k\left(k+1\right)}}\quad \quad s_2=\sum_{ k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{e(k)}{k\left(k+1\right)}}$$

The second sum is comptable by considering:
$$P(x,q)=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}{\left(1+x\left(q^{10^k}+…+q^{9\cdot 10^k}\right)\right)}$$
For the first a shifting using (in order tor replace the $\log_{10}(k)$ by a variable $n$) would produce :

$$s_2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\lfloor \log_{10}(k)\rfloor}{k\left(k+1\right)}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\sum_{k=10^n}^{10^{n+1}-1}{\frac{1}{k\left(k+1\right)}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{n}{10^n}-\frac{n}{10^{n+1}}\right)$$

I hope that this is helpful.